# Update field by code behind

Tags: calculated-column, spfield

I have an existing list with a text field and records in it. Now I want to change that text field into a calculated field to make it concat two other text fields in the list (possibly by changing the schema related to that field thru code behind). I've tried doing..

```
fieldThree.Type = SPFieldType.Calculated;
myList.Update();
SPFieldCalculated calcField = (SPFieldCalculated)fieldThree;
calcField.Formula = @"=CONCATENATE([fieldOne],"" "",[fieldTwo])";
calcField.Update();
```

As it seems.. I can't explicitly convert a text field to a calculated one.

Comment: @Cimares answer is correct. One side note: To update field definition you need to use `fieldThree.Update()` instead of `myList.Update`. In this case it will throw `Non-supported field type change` exception.

Answer (score 1):

As you've found, you can't convert a text field into a calculated one. What you'll have to do is add the calculated field as a new column.

If you want to do this through code you'll need to use the `SPList.Fields.Add()` method.